# Как отлаживать ошибки сторонних библиотек?

Tags: visual-studio, отладка

Не уверен в информативности заголовка вопроса. Поправьте пожалуйста, если необходимо.

Проблема вот в чем. При работе приложения меня выкидывает в ассемблер и я даже не могу найти то место в моем коде, откуда это начинается. То есть, возможно, это происходит в одном из фоновых потоков. Но в каком? Подскажите, как отлаживать такие вещи?

**UPD**

Я насколько понял, необработанное исключение возникает в каком то фоновом потоке, порожденном сторонней библиотекой. Поэтому я и не могу найти точку входа в своем коде.

**UPD2**

Stack Trace

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас исключение не в фоновом потоке, а в основном UI потоке. И вызывает его какой-то компонент DevExpress, в событии OnMouseMove. Для понимания проблемы, нужна полная информация об исключении, а не только стек.

Comment: @VadimTagil, тогда бы в стэк трейсе было белым помечено событие MouseMove. Но событие я не обрабатываю, его обрабатывает DevExpress сам своим пешком.

Comment: Я понимаю это. Вы так и не написали, при какое исключение (текст) и при каких действиях возникает.

Comment: @VadimTagil, написал, "При работе приложения меня выкидывает в ассемблер". Остальное не имеет значение. Ну возникает NullReferenceException. Но что это дает? С тем же успехом может вылезти любое другое исключение.

Comment: это дает многое) Нужно опираясь на твой стектрейс -- проверить все переменные на "налл" значение и сделать так что бы оно было не наллом, а со значением.

Comment: @Andrew, посмотри еще раз на стек трейс. Там нет созданного мной кода... весь код выполняется в системных библиотеках либо сторонних. Какие переменные я должен проверить?

Comment: NullReferenceException означает, что в используемом компоненте DevExpress баг. Убедитесь, что вы используете последнюю версию библиотеки и все делаете по инструкции. Если проблема не исчезает, сообщите об этом разработчику.

Answer (score 0):

1. Можешь почитать какую-либо инфу по теме "Отладка многопоточных приложений", уверен что-либо нагуглится.
2. Ты всегда можешь узнать откуда возникла ошибка просмотрев StackTrace ошибки.

Лично я бы выбрал 2. Отрепродьюсил бы ошибку 3-4 раза и сравнил бы стрек-трейсы. И попытатся локализировать проблему. После чего браться за фикс.

В твоем случае сложно посоветовать что-либо более конкретное т.к. сам вопрос совсем уж неконкретный.

Comment: Стэк трейс пустой... ну, то есть там все серым цветом написано.

Comment: попробуй запустить апликуху под релизом и без вижуалки. Возможно выдаст стектрейс) Или же пробуй локализировать проблему старым добрым способом расставив себе какие-либо позначки в разнопотоковых методах вроде Debug.WriteLine("MethodName"). Какой высветится последним перед ошибкой - там нужно и искать проблему.

Comment: но лучше увидеть стектрейс чем так извращатся. Просто подаю идею.

Comment: Полностью с вами согласен. Обновил вопрос. Вот стек трейс, подскажите что с ним делать дальше. Полный. Направление снизу вверх